# how to integrate google+ share functionality with ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-plus

I have simple erb template with following html code and javascript included.

```
<a class='share_on_gplus g-plus' data-social-action='share' data-medium='googleplus' data-content='q_name' href='https://plus.google.com/share?url=encodeURIComponent(URL).replace('%20','+') onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'','menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=auto,width=600');return false';">Share with Google+ </a>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx');

      }

    window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'en-US',
    parsetags: 'onload'
    };

  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); 
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js?onload=load';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();

</script>
```

My Google +API service is already on. When I click on share button in google plus popup I got an error:

> There was a problem saving your post. Please try again.
>   I am not able to share on google+. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to even load the plusone.js file at all if using the share URL rather than the button. Seems like there is something else going on. Are you using the JavaScript Client library for some other functionality on your site?

Comment: No I am using javaScript Client library only for google+ sharing.

Comment: In that case, you don't need to load the client.js file at all. You only need the plusone.js. You also don't need to set an API key for using the sharing or +1ing functionality. I would drop your "load" function and the onload parameter.

Comment: Same thing I have tried but unfortunately not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I need to mentioned the real domain name in url option and problem get solved. That's it!!!

Answer (score 3):

If that is a cut-and-paste from your code, I think there are at least two problems:

1) Your href value opens with a single quote, closes with a double quote, and has several single quotes as part of it.

2) The Google sharing code and bot use the attributes that are attached to the share element to determine exactly what is being shared, including the href attribute. It looks like you're trying to pop up a window on your own and manipulate the share this way.

I would start by trying to do a more basic share button (as documented either [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) or [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/)) and confirm that it can be used to share the page. If that does work, then you can start tailoring from there, but I don't think opening a new window will work the way you want.